# How to return single result from multiple table queries

Tags: php, sql-server

I am having trouble returning a single row from a query joining multiple tables in sql. I have a table containing customer info and another table that contains loan info.

The main objective is to fetch customers whose details are in the customers table by checking if they are in the loan table. If they are in loan table then fetch their details from the customers table.

But the issue is that I'm getting multiple rows of the same user's details based on the transaction they made. I just want a single row.

Here are my tables:

**Loans Table**
[image: Loan table]

in the loan table, you can see that the users appear multiple times.

**Cutomers Table**

In the customers table the user appears just once.

Lastly, my query table
[image: Query Output Layout on the client]

I just want the user to appear once.

the sql query:

```
$query = "
     SELECT * FROM loans 
     INNER JOIN customer ON loans.ac_no=customer.cust_no

     " ;
```

Comment: What columns do you need from the loan table? You can get result by grouping after join.

Answer (score 1):

Apply: DISTINCT Statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT expressions
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from customer where customer.cust_no in (select distinct loans.ac_no from loans);
```